# How to programatically update links in Alfresco?

Tags: java, alfresco

I need to create links for all the documents within a folder programatically. 
I managed to create the links successfully and my file link node looks similar to following:

```
 linkNode = nodeService.createNode(
   linkFolderNode, 
   ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS,
   QName.createQName(NamespaceService.CONTENT_MODEL_1_0_URI, display_Name),
   ApplicationModel.TYPE_FILELINK,
   props
 ).getChildRef();
```

display_Name here refers to the file name displayed.

However if you update the name of the original file it generates another link to the updated file. Is it possible to avoid this issue and maintain just a single link to a given file?

Comment: Where is the code you've posted running / being triggered?

Comment: @Gagravarr I have a folder called 'Documents' which has on create and update rule setup on it. Rule is associated with the action class 'CreateLink.java' Action class contains the above code.

Answer (score 1):

> display_Name here refers to the file name displayed.

`display_Name` is just link's name and may be different that linked object name.

[NodeService.createNode()](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/repository/NodeService.html#createNode-org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef-org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName-org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName-org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName-) returns [ChildAssociationRef](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/repository/ChildAssociationRef.html) class, that represents a child relationship between two nodes (`parent` and `child` - `link` that was created). 
[ChildAssociationRef.getChildRef()](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/repository/ChildAssociationRef.html#getChildRef--) returns created `link` [NodeRef](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/repository/NodeRef.html), for example: `workspace://SpacesStore/8dc27c51-cf23-4262-9431-f154edc913d0` (`NodeRef.toString()`). If you change name of the linked node, its `NodeRef` will not change.

Try this implementation:

```
public NodeRef createLink(NodeRef parentRef, NodeRef toLinkRef, 
                          boolean isDocument, String linkName){

    linkName = QName.createValidLocalName(linkName);
    QName linkQName = QName.createQName(NamespaceService.CONTENT_MODEL_1_0_URI, linkName);

    Map<QName, Serializable> props = new HashMap<QName, Serializable>();
    props.put(ContentModel.PROP_NAME, linkName);
    props.put(ContentModel.PROP_LINK_DESTINATION, toLinkRef);

    final NodeRef linkRef = nodeService.createNode(
        parentRef,
        ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS,
        linkQName,
        isDocument ? ApplicationModel.TYPE_FILELINK : ApplicationModel.TYPE_FOLDERLINK,
        props
    ).getChildRef();
    return linkRef;
}
```

You can use [`documentLinkService.createDocumentLink(toLinkRef,parentRef)`](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/repository/DocumentLinkService.html#createDocumentLink-org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef-org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef-) too, just inject it:

```
 <property name="documentLinkService" ref="DocumentLinkService" />
```